# Using ADO.Net DataSet and TableAdapter for populating combox with filter

Tags: c#, ado.net

I have a windows form with a dataset and tableadapter.

```
Table1 [id, action, info]
Table2 [id, actionId, command]

private void cbActions_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.optionsTableAdapter.Fill(this.actionsDS.Options);
        BindingSource source1 = new BindingSource();
        source1.DataSource = actionsDS;
        source1.Filter = "ActionId = " + cbActions.SelectedValue;
        cbOptions.DataSource = source1;
    }
```

I cant figure how to filter the sedond combobox (cbOptions) based on the first combobox (cbActions).

In sql I would use "SELECT options where actionid = 5" However, for simplicity I am trying to use the built in ado.net dataset and datatables.

It has to be easy and I must be close.

Answer (score 0):

Way over thinked it for hours yesterday.

```
int actionId = 5;
            ActionsDS.OptionsDataTable optionsDt = optionsTableAdapter.GetByActionId(actionId);
            cbOptions.DataSource = optionsDt;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's perhaps simpler to do with datarelations - you have 3 tables in your CarDataSet - Manufacturer, Model, Trim. There are DataRelations between them all, let's say they're named ManufacuterModel and ModelTrim

You open your data sources window, (view menu- other windows) and expand every node. You'll see you have top level nodes for Manufacturer, Model and Trim, but also under Manufacturer you have Model and under that you have Trim (and another Trim under the root model)

Drag Manufacturer to the form to create a DataGridView, drag the Model that is a child of Manufacturer to the form, and drag the Trim that is a child of Model

You should now have 3 bindingsources, but critically:

- the manufacturer bindingsource binds to the DataSet table
- the model bs binds to the Manufacturer bs and has a datamember set to the name of the ManufacturerModel relation
- the trim bs binds to the model bs and has a datamember of ModelTrim

Run the app; selecting a parent row in the Manufacturer grid filters the Model grid to cars from that manuf, and the trim refines to just grind of the first model. Select a model and the trims change etc

Stop the program (it was just to demo it working) and put combo boxes bound to those bindingsources, remove the grids (unless you were using the combos to drive grids in which case maybe the grids are better for your UI

Don't forget that this can only work if the datatables are full of data (that is related) - if you have thousands of manufacturers, models and trims it'd be a big DataSet (and selective loading would be better, but it's more complex)